# Escaping single quotes for shell

Tags: ruby, string, shell, escaping

I'm passing ENVs with JSON into Docker. I need to use a string on the shell for a parameter. In the shell, the right way to escape a single quote is by using `'\''`. So, `"Tom's Market"` becomes `"Tom'\''s Market"` as in:

```
docker run -it -e FOO='["Tom'\''s Market"]' ...
```

Ruby's Shellwords does not appear to do this.

```
Shellwords.shellescape('["Tom\'s Market"]')
#=> \[\"Tom\'s\ Market\"\]
```

So I wanted to use simple find/replace:

```
'["Tom\'s Market"]'.gsub("'", "'\\''")
#=> ["Tom's Market"]'s Market"]
```

I don't know what's going on there. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, backslash is how you escape in ruby strings. To escape it you need another backslash.

The is usually to add backslashes until it works

```
puts %q{["Tom's Market"]}.gsub("'", "'\\\\''")
# ["Tom'\''s Market"]
```

Comment: As much as I hate to admit it, at least once in my life I've added backslashes until it worked, too...

Answer (score 0):

`Shellwords.escape`'s result is meant to be used **unquoted:**

```sh
docker run -it -e FOO=\[\"Tom\'s\ Market\"\]
```